# AutoQuery/OrmLite incorrect total value when using joins

Tags: servicestack

I have this autoquery implementation

```
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request).SelectDistinct();

var results = Db.Select<ProductDto>(q);

return new QueryResponse<ProductDto>
{
    Offset = q.Offset.GetValueOrDefault(0),
    Total = (int)Db.Count(q),
    Results = results
};
```

The request has some joins:

```
public class ProductSearchRequest : QueryDb<GardnerRecord, ProductDto>
    , ILeftJoin<GardnerRecord, RecordToBicCode>, ILeftJoin<RecordToBicCode, GardnerBicCode>
{

}
```

The records gets returned correctly but the total is wrong. I can see 40,000 records in database but it tells me there is 90,000.  There is multiple `RecordToBicCode` for each `GardnerRecord` so it's giving me the number of records multiplied by the number of `RecordToBicCode`.

How do I match the total to the number of `GardnerRecord` matching the query?

I am using PostgreSQL so need the count statement to be like

```
select count(distinct r.id) from gardner_record r etc...
```

Dores OrmLite have a way to do this?

I tried:

```
            var q2 = q;
            q2.SelectExpression = "select count(distinct \"gardner_record\".\"id\")";
            q2.OrderByExpression = null;
            var count = Db.Select<int>(q2);
```

But I get object reference not set error.

Answer (score 0):

AutoQuery is returning the correct total count for your query of which has left joins so will naturally return more results then the original source table.

You can perform a Distinct count with:

```
Total = Db.Scalar<long>(q.Select(x => Sql.CountDistinct(x.Id));
```